# PhpShtorm настроить отслеживание импортированных SCSS файлов в основном, и пересобирать css каждый раз, когда произведены изменения в любом из файлов

Tags: scss, jetbrains

Есть основной SCSS файл в который импортированы остальные
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в IDe настроен filewatcher, при редактировании этих файлов css пересобирается отдельно для каждого.
Но на сайте изменения не видны, так как к нему подключен только основной Scss, и пока в нем не будут внесены изменения, общий Css не пересобретеся.

То есть как только я в основном что-то изменил, то на сайте сразу становятся видны все изменения в том числе с импортированных файлов.

Но это не удобно, потому что каждый раз после редактирования нужного файла мне приходится делать какие нибудь действия и в основном файле, чтобы увидеть результат.

Как включить отслеживания всех зависимых файлов, и пересобирать весь CSS даже если в основном файле, никаких изменений не было?

Как то год назад настраивал это, но после обновления phpshtorm все слетело. нагуглить не получае6тся.

Comment: Вообще это должно работать по умолчанию. Приложите снимок настроек вашего file watcher-а

Comment: Решил вопрос, импортировав настройки с другого компьютера, но watcher ы одинаковые, хз где еще эта настройка скрыта)